# how to use i18next in react native for localisation

Tags: javascript, react-native, localization, i18next, react-i18next

i18next is not able to parse the key of json if it contains dots(.) in the key *i.e. ngb.pagination.last-aria* . Also facing issue with interpolation too. Please have a look on bellow code.

Please note : I can not change json file key or its value as it is being used in web and now we are going to use that in our native app.

// **en_en.json**

```
"has-expired": "<ph name=\"INTERPOLATION\"><ex>{{alert.uniqueId}}</ex>{{alert.uniqueId}}</ph> has expired.",
"ngb.pagination.last-aria": "Last",
"hi":"hello"
```

// **i18n.js**

```
// import { Localization } from 'expo';

import i18next from 'i18next';
import { initReactI18next } from 'react-i18next';

// translation files

import en from './en/en_gb.json';
import de from './de/de_de.json';
import fr from './fr/fr_fr.json';

const resources = {
  en: { translation: en },
  de: { translation: de },
  fr: { translation: fr },
};

// Config
i18next.use(initReactI18next).init({
  resources,
  lng: 'en',
  fallbackLng: 'en',
  returnObjects: true,
});

// TODO
export function t(name: string, params = {}) {
  return i18next.t(`${name}`, params);
}

export default i18next;
```

// **component**

```
<Text>{i18next.t('has-expired', { alert: { uniqueId: 20 } })}</Text>

<Text>{i18next.t('ngb.pagination.last-aria'}</Text>

<Text>{i18next.t('hi'}</Text>
```

// **output**

```
<ph name=\"INTERPOLATION\"><ex>{{alert.uniqueId}}</ex>20</ph> has expired.

ngb.pagination.last-aria

Hello
```

Answer (score 0):

For the interpolation I think you are escaping so try to change \ or use

```
i18next.t('keyEscaped', { myVar: '<img />', interpolation: { escapeValue: false } });
```

Related to dots, them are treated as separators so you can use like this

```
- replace dot with `&#46;`
```

Comment: thanks , related to dot issue fixed after adding keySeparator: '&#46;' 
but to fix interpolation I tried icu syntax but not able to remove those <ph> & <ex> tags.
current output is :
```<ph><ex>20</ex>20</ph> has expired.```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use dots(.), i18next will automatically separate the key and expect nested JSON. If you want to treat the dots as flat JSON, you can set the `keySeparator` config option to `false` in i18next.

If you use [i18nexus.com](https://i18nexus.com) to manage your i18next translations, you can go to the Export tab and set "Key Separation" to Disabled.

Comment: I have resolved (.) issue thanks.
But what about the other syntax . We are using POeditor to manage .